# Binding to a TextBox inside an ItemsControl ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

The binding on my ItemsControl ItemsTemplate does not work. I've gone through some other similar stack overflow questions but I cannot figure out the problem with my binding. Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong with my binding?

Excerpt from my MainWindow's ViewModel;

```
private ObservableCollection<uint> words;
private uint word;
private int numberOfWords;

public ObservableCollection<uint> Words
{
    get
    {
        return this.words;
    }

    set
    {
        this.words = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.Words);
    }
}

public uint Word
{
    get
    {
        return this.word;
    }

    set
    {
        this.word = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.Word);
    }
}

public int NumberOfWords
{
    get
    {
        return this.numberOfWords;
    }

    set
    {
        this.numberOfWords = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.NumberOfWords);

        this.Words.Clear();

        for (uint x = 0; x < value; x++)
        {
            this.Words.Add(this.Word);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the below ItemsControl inside a user control. The MainWindow has its DataContext set to a ViewModel, which the ItemsControl uses. The ItemsSource binding works and I get however many textboxes I specify, but when putting a value in the TextBox, the binding does not work.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="8" ItemsSource="{Binding Words}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Word}" Width="125" Height="25" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I saw one post that talks about using this type of binding below, but apparently, I do not understand FindAncestor, so I do not know if I am on the right track or not with this.

```
Text="{Binding Path=Word, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
```

Comment: `Word` property looks like selected item. Why do you want to bind each `TextBox.Text` to the same property? Do you mean `<TextBox Text="{Binding}" Width="125" Height="25" />`? This will bind `TextBox` to each item

Comment: I do mean to set binding of each TextBox to each item and did not understand that about binding, but when I change my TextBox binding and run it, I get the following error when setting the NumberOfWords property: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath

Comment: change binding to `Text="{Binding Path=.}"`

Comment: This doesn't make sense, as the DataContext within the DataTemplate will be one of the uints from the collection Words.  uint doesn't have a public property called Word.  Also, it wouldn't work even if you were doing it right.  You cannot alter a uint inside of a collection via a binding.  Bindings don't work like that.  You'd need to create a Word class that has a public property of type uint, and you would bind against that property.  This is just all kinds of nope here.

Comment: @dkozl That looked like it worked on the view because I see a zero in each TextBox now. But I still do not see the property Word getting hit when I enter a value, when I have a breakpoint there. And when I check my property Words, I do not see any change.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to understand and fix my all kinds of nope @Will. This is the first time I've worked with an ItemControl and trying to understand it. What you say does make sense. I will re-work my view and see what I can get from that. Thanks.

Comment: Because you're not binding to `Word` but to each item. There is only one `Word` property per list and you have multiple `TextBox` but anyway I overlooked fact it's `uint` and @Will is right. If you change `TextBox` it won't update element in collection.

Comment: @Will, I have been trying to figure out how to get your solution to work, but apparently I do not understand it enough. Can you please expand on your comments with an example into an answer for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot bind to elements in a collection and then change the element itself--you can only change *properties* of this element through the binding.  In other words, given the following collection

> [ "one", "two", "three" ]

through a binding such as

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Words[0]} /> <!-- the word "one" is displayed in the tb -->
```

if you change "one" to "derp" you would not alter the collection to

> [ "derp", "two", "three" ]

To apply this to your example, you would want to bind the collection to the ItemsControl, then in the template bind to each instance within the collection and change *properties* of this instance.

First, create your Model.  This holds your data and is what you bind against in the UI.

```
public sealed class Word 
{ 
    public uint Value {get;set;}
}
```

Next, expose a collection of these on your View Model.

```
public sealed class ViewModel
{
    //create and fill in ctor
    public ObservableCollection<Word> WordsYo {get;private set;}
}
```

Next, bind your ItemsControl's ItemsSource to this property and bind elements in the template to the properties of Word:

```
<!-- Window.DataContext is set to an instance of ViewModel -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WordsYo}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The Aristocrats.

Comment: Works great! Thank you for explaining like you did...made it very easy to follow.